# How to connect to Windows PC in graphical mode?

Tags: 12.04, windows, ssh, lan

My basic desktop PC uses Ubuntu 12.04. However for work I need a few programs (like Hec-Ras) that I didn't succeed to run trough wine or play on linux.

I thought of easy solution: to connect Windows PC in graphical mode. I can succeed with it using TeamViewer, however I'd like to connect trough my local network. How do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

Misery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [Teamviewer for Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer#Linux_port) if you are familiar with it.

Otherwise you have 2 options, RDP or VNC.

**RDP** is **windows Remote desktop sharing** and there are **linux clients** for it like [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/). Advantage of RDP is windows side setup is relatively easier.

Install the [rdesktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rdesktop/) package, then from a terminal window use the following command line:

```
rdesktop -u REMOTE_USER_NAME -g 1024x768 REMOTE_HOST
```

It opens a remote session for the `REMOTE_USER_NAME` on the `REMOTE_HOST`. The screen (window) resolution is set through the `-g` parameter.

**VNC** is more **well known on Linux**. There are several servers you can use on Windows([UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/)  is one that I have some experience with) to share your desktop and then connect using the **inbuild VNC client** in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try [tightvnc](http://tightvnc.org/).  TightVNC is a free remote control software package. With TightVNC, you can see the desktop of a remote machine and control it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rdesktop to access windows PCs from a linux box. or check whether your distribution is having remote desktop client. Create a new connection in that and use the protocol remote desktop protocol.