# How to run Windows app on Ubuntu? [NOT wine]

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04. Is there a way to run windows app (an *.exe) on Ubuntu without using *Wine*? I need to use SSH. I know you can use *Putty* to run linux program on windows, but can it be done vice-versa? I mean: using SSH client to run Windows app on linux.

Regards.

Comment: Putty isn't running Linux apps on Windows. The apps are run on Linux.

Comment: If is that program written in .NET Framework, you can use mono.

Comment: hello @tomsk, can you give the more detail about the mono so I can check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can also install a SSH-Server on Windows (e.g. https://www.openssh.com/) and than call a programm by SSH from your Linux-Client to the command line on your Windows Host-Machine.

Or use something like https://www.teamviewer.com/de

Or look here: [How to connect to Windows PC in graphical mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205643/how-to-connect-to-windows-pc-in-graphical-mode?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot run Windows (GUI) programs remotely over SSH. You can use CLI tools if you have an SSH server running on your Windows machine or VM. You can use RDP (like VNC) to use programs remotely, however.

You can run Windows inside a VM under Ubuntu, and then run whatever apps you need, inside that VM.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTy is a ssh client available for both Windows and Linux. It does not run linux applications on windows.

Cygwin is a project that ports linux applications to windows.

https://www.cygwin.com/

I have installed KDE on windows using cygwin for example, or cygwin provides an X server for Windows.

You can run a ssh server on Windows, cygwin is one option, and connect from Linux.

What is it you are wanting to do exactly ?